# Can you provide a lower bound on $|\zeta (s) |$ for fixed $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1$?

Tags: analysis, riemann-zeta

It's easy to prove, for example, that $|\zeta(2 + it)| > 2 - \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.  However, there is some $\sigma > 1$ for which $\zeta ( \sigma ) = 2$, and it is more difficult to obtain a lower bound on $|\zeta (\sigma' + it) |$ for $1<\sigma' \leq \sigma$.  Can you provide a non-trivial lower bound?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Claim:
$$
|\zeta(s)| >\frac{\pi^2}{15}(\sigma-1).
$$
Proof:
We compare Euler products to see
$
1/|\zeta(s)|<\zeta(\sigma)/\zeta(2\sigma)
$,
so
$$
|\zeta(s)|>\frac{\zeta(2\sigma)}{\zeta(\sigma)}>\frac{\pi^2}{15}(\sigma-1),
$$
since the linear lower bound is tight at $\sigma=1$ and $\sigma=2$ and the function is concave down.

For $\sigma=1$, there's no known lower bound that's independent of $t$ (and thus constant.)  Titchmarsh *Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function* proves that $1/\zeta(1+i t)=O(\log(t)^7)$ so
$$
|\zeta(1+i t)|> C\log(t)^{-7},
$$
for some $C$ which can be made explicit by carefully reading his proof.

There are some more modern results - Kevin Ford has a couple of papers (with *Riemann Zeta Function* in the title.)

Comment: Is it possible to do better for $Re(s) = 1$?